# Directly logged into Guest account

Tags: users, guest-session

I have just one user in Ubuntu and that is guest and cannot do anything else. I installed Ubuntu and it directly logged me into a guest account.

*How do I create new accounts without proper access?*

Comment: Check with `ls /home` what the users are. There should be 1 that is your admin and you used to create the system. Reset its password if you cant remember what is was (there are topics about that on AU) and login with that user. From then it will use that user to login.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Ubuntu, it asked for a user and password before it copied any files to the drive.

You can [add users](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps) with `adduser`

> sudo adduser *UserID*

It will ask for the SU password if you had assigned one.

Answer (score 0):

You can login as root and change the password for the default user (other than guest) to whatever you want it to be, then proceed as normal.

You can alternatively login as root and do as LDC3 suggested, add a new user with the adduser command.

You won't be able to do his recommending in a default installation because root won't have a password... and also you would have to login using an sudo activated account to use the sudo command.

There are a number of ways to gain access to a computer that you have physical access to.  The easiest way is to boot into the recovery mode.  If you have a multiple boot installation, you will automatically have a boot menu.  If you don't get a boot menu, you can activate this menu by holding down the shift key while the system boots.

- From the boot menu choose the "Advance options for Ubuntu" option.
- Then go into the recovery mode option
- Choose the Drop to root shell prompt
- remount the drive into read/write mode:
   `mount -o remount,rw
  /dev/sda1`.
  You can check the boot drive with `df -v`.
  Add a new user with:
  `adduser [newuser]`
- Add the new user to the sudo group with:
  `adduser [newuser] sudo`

Now you can reboot your computer and use the newly created account.